# RSpec test to check (Rails model: validates :something, :inclusion => list from other activeRecord)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec2, factory-bot

Below is the code that I am using:

This is my `app/models` file:

```
class One < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :surname      
end

class Two < ActiveRecord::Base  
  attr_accessible :name, :one_surname

  # generate a list of one's surnames
  def self.LIST_SURNAMES
    list  = Array.new
    arr   = One.all
    arr.each {|one| list << one.surname}

    return list
  end

  validates :one_surname, :inclusion => self.LIST_SURNAMES()
end
```

This is my `/spec/models` file:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :two do
    name "two_name"
  end

  factory :one do
    name "one_name"
    surname "one_surname"
  end    
end

describe Two do
  it 'should be created' do
    @one = FactoryGirl.create(:one)

    puts "One.last.surname = #{One.last.surname}"
    puts "Two.LIST_SURNAMES = #{Two.LIST_SURNAMES}"

    @two = FactoryGirl.build(:two, :one_surname => Two.LIST_SURNAMES[0])

    @two.save!
  end
end
```

However, my test fails. And I'm entirely unsure of why this is. Any thoughts?

This is the `RSpec` output:

```
One.last.surname  = one_surname
Two.LIST_SURNAMES = ["one_surname"]
```

Further, I am getting this failure:

```
  1) Two should be created
     Failure/Error: @two.save!
     ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
       Validation failed: One surname is not included in the list
 # ./category_spec.rb:29:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Comment: Can you change `@two.save.should eq(true)` to be `@two.save!` and see what error is preventing the save?

Comment: @JesseWolgamott, `Validation failed: One surname is not included in the list`

Comment: ok, and right before that, can you `put Two.LIST_SURNAMES` ... I'd like to verify it contains "one_surname"

Comment: @JesseWolgamott, for previous question -> `Two.LIST_SURNAMES = ["one_surname"]`; and for `puts "One.last.inspect"`-> `#<One id: 183, name: "one_name", surname: "one_surname", created_at: "2012-06-06 15:19:59", updated_at: "2012-06-06 15:19:59">`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's executing the Two.LIST_SURNAMES at interpretation time, not runtime. So if you want it to get the LIST_SURNAMES at runtime, you'll need to use a proc

```
validates :one_surname, :inclusion => {:in => proc {self.LIST_SURNAMES()}}
```

The rest is optional, but here's some cleaned code:

```
class Two < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :one_surname

  validates :one_surname, :inclusion => {in: proc{One.pluck(:surname)}}                                              
end
```

I replaced the `LIST_SURNAMES` method with `One.pluck(:surname)` which does the same thing. Also: LIST_SURNAMES, if you keep it, should be `def self.list_surnames` since it is not a constant.

Comment: That's a marvelous answer. Thank you.